# pulseaudio, replaced by jackd on demand only

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack

I've rediscovered jackd, because I have to ... to use bitwig. I would like to have a setup like this:

- only pulseaudio running when everythign goes normal, ie office work, etc., as for me it seems intuitive, for example when using web conferencing, etc. jackd is not suited well for quickly choosing the right micro to be used in the browser, also, I manually must use QAMixer to make my headphones work...
- jackd runs when I use bitwig (or other programms that support it). I dont mind manually starting it.
- I also dont mind if I cannot listen to youtube videos anymore when using bitwig.

I have tried these tools: ubuntio studio control, qjackctl, and pulsaudio-module-jack is installed. I dont yet really get how all of there work together, or bite each other.

Answer (score 0):

Found the following solution:

- only do install these `sudo apt install jackd qjackctl`
- using `pasuspender -- alsamixer` as pulsaudio stopper, AND quick volume changer via up down arrows
- then starting qjackctl, and the bitwig, or whatever other software needed
- no magic :-)

would probably work without qjackctl, as jackd is communicating via dbus, so bitwig could start it on demand. I prefer to know what's happening exactly - dbus support can be disabled in qjackctl > setup > misc - more on this [here](https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?t=17176)

ocenaudio works with jack, whereas I didnt get VLC to connect/use it (for now, on it's wiki it says it's capable!). Firefox and Chrome dont work either... not a real issue for me.

**Pipewire UPDATE**

There is [Pipewire](https://pipewire.org/), and it looks very promising.

But it still means a lot of manual work in Ubuntu 22.04: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/pipewire-replace-pulseaudio-ubuntu-2204/